# Powershell auto completion escapes special characters AND uses single quotes

Tags: powershell

I have written a powershell cmdlet that takes a path as parameter. The path may contain special characters like [ and spaces.

A user complained that the script wouldn't handle escaped paths when using auto completion. This is what powershell produces when auto-complete such a path:

```
.\myscript.ps1 '.\file`[bla`].dot'
```

My questions:

1. Why does powershell auto completion use single-quotes *and* escapes special characters? Isn't that wrong? It should do either one or the other, but not both.
2. What is the correct way to deal with such parameters?

Comment: Will do, but first I need to understand it. The thing is that I come from the UNIX world where these things used to be a no-brainer.

Comment: Got it. FWIW, PowerShell's behavior is questionable here, and I will post an issue on GitHub to follow up.

Comment: Re Unix: The main difference is that in PowerShell you cannot use quoted vs. unquoted to distinguish between wildcard (globbing) patterns and literal names; e.g., `'*.txt'` and `*.txt` as command arguments behave the same, and it is up to the command being invoked to either treat it as a pattern or as a literal - hence the distinct `-Path` (pattern) and `-LiteralPath` (literal) parameters on file-processing cmdlets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does powershell auto completion use single-quotes and escapes special characters?

Because the `` ` ``-escaping isn't *string*-interpolation escaping (which only applies to `"..."` strings), it is escaping of [*wildcard-pattern*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards) metacharacters, which happen to use the same escape character as string-interpolation escaping, `` ` ``.
In other words: by design, the `` ` `` chars. are *retained* as part of the verbatim `'...'` string, to be interpreted later during wildcard-pattern processing.
See the "Background information" section below, which discusses when PowerShell's tab completion assumes that a filename argument isn't just a literal name but a wildcard pattern, as is the case here.

> What is the correct way to deal with such parameters?

To **prevent the escaping**, make sure that your script's (first positional) **parameter is named

`-LiteralPath` (parameter variable name `$LiteralPath`)**.

A quick demonstration with a function:

```
# Tab-completing an argument that binds to a -LiteralPath parameter deactivates
# escaping.
function foo { param($LiteralPath) $LiteralPath }; foo .\file[bla].dot
```

This requirement is unfortunate, since the name `-LiteralPath` isn't always appropriate - and, unfortunately, using a different name in combination with an [`[Alias('LiteralPath')`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.AliasAttribute) attribute does *not* work.

**If you need to use a different parameter name**, you can **roll your own, *unescaped* file-name tab completion**, via an [`[ArgumentCompleterAttribute()]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ArgumentCompleterAttribute) attribute:

```
function foo {
 param(
  [ArgumentCompleter({ 
      param($unused1, $unused2, $wordToComplete)
      (Get-Item ('{0}*' -f ($wordToComplete -replace '[][]', '``$&'))).Name
  })]
  $SomeParam
 ) 
 $SomeParam  # echo for diagnostic purposes
}
foo .\file[bla].dot
```

Note:

- This simplistic implementation only works with files in the *current* directory, but can be adapted to work with all paths.
- Note the use of verbatim ``` `` ``` in the replacement string, which is a workaround for a bug described in [GitHub issue #7999](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7999).

---

An **alternative** is to *not* try to fix the tab-completion behavior and instead ***unescape* the argument** received, which should work even when the argument *isn't* escaped:

```
function foo { param($SomeParam) [WildcardPattern]::Unescape($SomeParam) }
# The escaped path is now unescaped inside the function.
foo '.\file`[bla`].dot'
```

<sup>Note: In the unlikely event that you have file names that contain *literal* `` `[ `` and `` `] `` sequences and the user *types or pastes* such a literal name, the approach would malfunction. In fact, even tab-completion with escaping fails in this case, as of v7.1.0; e.g. verbatim `` `[ `` turns to escaped ``` ``[ ```, even though it should be ```` ```[ ````</sup>

---

**Caveat**:

- If you do use **file paths that contain `[` and `]` *unescaped***, you have to **make sure that you use the `-LiteralPath` parameter** when you pass these paths to file-processing cmdlets such as `Get-Item`, `Get-ChildItem` or `Get-Content` later.

---

**Background information**:

**For any parameter name other than `-LiteralPath`**, notably `-Path`, **PowerShell assumes that the parameter is designed to accept [wildcard expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards)** and therefore escapes wildcard metacharacters that occur *verbatim* in file names with `` ` ``; since `*` and `?` cannot be part of file names (at least on Windows), this effectively applies to `[` and `]`.

Note that `` ` `` is *not* a *string-interpolation* escape character in this case: given that a verbatim *single*-quoted string (`'...'`) is used in the completion, the `` ` `` characters are *preserved*. However, if you use such a string in a context where a *wildcard expression* is expected, it is the wildcard engine that then recognizes `` ` `` as *its* escape character.

Conversely, this means that if you use an [expandable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) (interpolating) *double*-quoted string (`"..."`), you must use ``` `` ``` to escape wildcard metacharacters - and tab-completion indeed does that if you start your argument with `"`

---

**As of v7.1, PowerShell's tab-completion behavior with respect to file names is somewhat unfortunate:**

It is reasonable default behavior to perform *file-name* completion for any parameters whose completion behavior isn't implied by their type (e.g., an `[enum]`-derived type) or where no custom completion logic is specified (such as via [`[ArgumentCompleterAttribute()]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ArgumentCompleterAttribute) or [`[ValidateSet()]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ValidateSetAttribute) attributes).

However:

- It is *questionable* whether it makes sense to assume that all such parameters *by default* support wildcard expressions, except for the seemingly hard-coded `-LiteralPath` exception.

  - Ideally, wildcard support should solely be inferred from the presence of a [`[SupportsWildcards()]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.SupportsWildcardsAttribute) on the target parameter - see [GitHub suggestion #14149](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14149)
  - Presumably, the reason that wildcard support is assumed by default is that **the file-processing cmdlets' first positional parameter is the wildcard-based `-Path` parameter** (e.g. `Get-ChildItem *.txt`), for which escaping of verbatim `[` and `]` *is* needed.

    - While the escaping makes it easier to pass arguments to such cmdlets *positionally*, this also means that if an argument is *not* obtained by tab-completion - such as by typing or pasting the name - escaping must be performed too, which may be unexpected.
    - Conversely, code that expects *unescaped* paths and uses `-LiteralPath` with file-processing cmdlets breaks with an escaped path resulting from tab completion.
- It is *pointless* to perform file-name completion on *type-constrained* parameters whose type is something *other* than `[string]` or `[System.IO.FileInfo]` / `[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]` (or arrays thereof).

  - For instance, `function foo { param([int] $i) }` currently unexpectedly also tab-completes file names, even though that makes no sense (and breaks the call, if it is attempted).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was fixed in powershell 7.  In powershell 5 you'd have to use -literalpath.

```
dir '.\file`[1`].txt'

    Directory: C:\Users\js\foo

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a---          11/17/2020  9:04 AM              5 file[1].txt
```

Comment: It seems to work somehow for built-in cmdlets, but I am talking about my own cmdlet.

Comment: That was my mistake: I naively thought `Get-Item` and `Get-ChildItem` behave the same, but they don't, so `Get-ChildItem` with an escaped path is indeed still broken in Windows PowerShell (v5.1), and probably won't get fixed (but, as you state, it has been fixed in PowerShell [Core]). In Windows PowerShell you have to _double_ the backticks to make it work with `Get-ChildItem`, which is a problem that also still affects PowerShell [Core] in _other_ areas - see [GitHub issue #7999](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7999)

Comment: That said, this problem is incidental to the question at hand: Richard wants the file name to tab-complete _unescaped_, for binding to a custom script's parameter.